# Reversing C# exe,Questions.Help

Tags: debugging, memory, decompile, c#, memory-dump

I am trying to debugging c# .NET application which receives a set of doubles and keep it as DataSeries every second.

I want to rewrite its dataseries before the new data comes with my own dataset.

1st question.
my idea is the following:
if I find the address on RAM where the data kept,I can rewrite with python or MHS.

is this valid?

2nd question.
what does something like "@06000027" in DnSpy mean?[image]

thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers are metadata and is called Token IDs. You can click on those in the dnSpy and you will be taken to the editor of the selected item.

As for your first question, remember that .net apps are JITed before the actual executions so addresses will change. If I would have to do this I would change the code on the .net level.